# Check the opend or closed state of an accordian

Tags: html, html-framework-7

I am intending to check in an accordian that any item is open or not .
How can this be achieved in Framework7.

i can open the accordian item by this-

```
myApp.accordionOpen(".accordion-item");
```

i can close the accordian item by this -

```
myApp.accordionClose(".accordion-item");
```

but how can i check if any accordian item is already opened or closed.
[Refering this link for the accordian used.](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/accordion.html#.VOxIVvmUeDs)
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the `accordion-item` has the class `accordion-item-expanded` with the `hasClass('accordion-item-expanded')`-Method.

http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/dom.html#.VOxXGFOG9to

Comment: if( $$("li").hasClass(".'accordion-item-expanded") )
{ //do this }

Comment: Depending on what you need, it might not be totally correct. Depending on the use-case you should call the `hasClass`-method directly on a existing instance of the accordion-item. But if you just want to check if any of the accordions is opened, you could do something like this:

`if($$(".accordion-item.accordion-item-expanded").length > 0) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Look here at the documentation: [Accordion Docs](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/accordion.html#accordion-events)

From the docs:

```
var myApp = new Framework7();

var $$ = Dom7;

$$('.accordion-item').on('opened', function() {
  //Your code here
});
```

Execute any code you need if the accordion is opened.